# Content after very 8 blocks

Tags: smarty, smarty3

So after struggling for a while with smarty I am now trying to figure out how to put extra content in my product list after every 6 blocks. Does anyone know how to do this?

Best wishes,

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```php
{for $i = 0; $i < count($foo); $i++}
    {$foo[$i].content}
    {if ($i + 1) % 6}
        {$extracontent}
    {/if}
{/for}
```